# Reassign Contact Associated to Community User

Tags: community, customer-portal, user-record

I am not finding a way to change the contact that the community user is associated to.  I have tried the following:

1) Upload/Download via Data Loader - FAIL - Data Loader cannot see ContactId on update

2) Workbench Active or Inactive Community User - FAIL - I get a un-known exception when I try to change ContactId.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Has anyone tried via APEX? I am about to

Comment: @PeterHerzog how have you just gotten on sfse? welcome :)

ps - i'm obligated to remind you to search first before posting a question :troll:

Comment: @RalphCallaway Oops! Sorry Ralph!!